# VBA Excel - Resolving Error 13 when deleting text from a field

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

Have a spreadsheet I am editing for a project at work. The sheet uses string values in col 1, 3, 4, and 5. Multiple people will be accessing this sheet so in order to maintain a clean appearance I have set the sheet to capitalize the values in each of those columns upon entry.

```
    Dim letter as String
    Select Case Target.Column
        Case Is = 1, 3, 4, 5
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            letter = Target.Value
            letter = UCase(letter)
            Target.Value = letter
    End Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
```

This works great except for when you drag and select multiple fields to delete. It returns run-time error 13 and I know it is from the letter string becoming " " and the program can't capitalize a blank string.

I can't wrap my brain around how to bypass this Select if the letter string is blank. I've spent some considerable time looking for the answer but can't seem to find something that applies to this situation. Any input is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Your type mismatch is NOT from the UCase(letter) line.  UCase("") will just return "".  Your type mismatch is in the line before that - "letter = Target.Value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, your problem is not in the UCase line.

Try this:

```
Dim letter as String
Dim cell As Variant

Application.EnableEvents = False 
For each cell in Target
    Select Case cell.column
        Case Is = 1, 3, 4, 5
             Cell.Value = UCase(Cell.Value)
    End Select
Next cell

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: This works, thank you very much. Sorry I didn't see your other comment.

Comment: Wasn't suggesting you should have seen it, was just referencing it.  Made the comment when I wasn't sure if I'd have time to fix the whole thing, but then realized it would be a quick fix.

Comment: No worries! Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try an if statement to test for an empty string

```
Dim letter as String
Select Case Target.Column
    Case Is = 1, 3, 4, 5
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        letter = Target.Value

        If Len(letter) > 0 then
             letter = UCase(letter)
             Target.Value = letter
        Else
             Target.Value = letter
        End IF
End Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: removed: This removed the error when deleting multiple fields but it broke the capitalization. It will capitalize the first box that I enter, but after that it doesn't work. No run-time errors either.

Comment: My initial reply was incorrect I had another issue with my code.

The code is still returning a runtime error 13 for the initialization of letter when it's set to Target.Value.

Comment: I was away for awhile.  It looks like @OpiesDad gave you a solid solution.